# How to show only three rows of table in wordpress using jQuery

Tags: wordpress

I want to show only three records of table in wordpress . I am trying to write the code in jQuery to hide it but it is not working this is my html code

```
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"></tr>
```

**this is my jQuery code to show the three rows of tables in wordpress using jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

console.log("check");
  jQuery("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 3).show();

});

</script>
```

Comment: You can try adding your code in footer

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583233/show-only-a-limited-number-of-rows-in-a-table

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"><td>4</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>5</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"><td>6</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="odd"><td>7</td></tr>
<tr role="row" class="even"><td>8</td></tr>

</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery("table > tbody > tr").hide().slice(0, 3).show();

  });

</script>
```